# Getting absolute coordinates of element drawn with d3

Tags: d3.js, coordinates, absolute

I am drawing a circle inside a group with d3, but I need to calculate the absolute coordinates of the circle after drag and drop the group, because sometimes I have to add new elements near the circle.

The problem is with the function **getScreenCTM**, when I execute appears **getScreenCTM is not a function**. I can't see the problem.

[Link](https://svg1.000webhostapp.com/)

My Source Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>FAM</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v4.min.js"></script>      
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.min.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var svg = d3.select('#svf');

                var container = svg.append('g');
                var object = null, line = null, path = null, i = 0, j = 0;
                var pointspath = new Array();

                function cuadricula(container) {
                    for (i = 0; i < 860; i = i + 10) {
                        container.append('line').attr('x1', i).attr('y1', 0).attr('x2', i).attr('y2', 860).attr('stroke', '#CFCECE').attr('stroke-width', 1).attr('fill', 'none');
                    }

                    for (j = 0; j < 460; j = j + 10) {
                        container.append('line').attr('x1', 1).attr('y1', j).attr('x2', 860).attr('y2', j).attr('stroke', '#CFCECE').attr('stroke-width', 1).attr('fill', 'none');
                    }
                }

                cuadricula(container);

                function main() {
                    var coords = d3.mouse(this), x = coords[0], y = coords[1];
                    var lnk = $('#dv_conv').find('a[data-pressed="1"]');
                    var conv = lnk.attr('data-conv');

                    if (conv == 1) {
                        var grp = container.append('g').attr('class', 'gwoman');
                        grp.append('circle').attr('class', 'woman').attr('name', '').attr('age', '').attr('job', '').attr('cx', x).attr('cy', y).attr('r', 20).attr('stroke-width', 2).attr('stroke', '#000').attr('fill', 'transparent');
                        grp.on('click', clicked).call(d3.drag().on('start', dragstarted).on('drag', dragged_woman).on('end', dragended))
                    }

                    if (conv == 2) {
                        container.append('rect').attr('nombre', '').attr('edad', '').attr('ocupacion', '').attr('x', x).attr('y', y).attr('width', 40).attr('height', 40).attr('stroke-width', 2).attr('stroke', '#000').attr('fill', 'transparent').on('click', clicked).call(d3.drag().on('start', dragstarted).on('drag', dragged_rect).on('end', dragended));
                    }

                    if (conv == 5) {
                        container.append('text').attr('x', x).attr('y', y).text('Hello World').on('click', clicked).call(d3.drag().on('start', dragstarted).on('drag', dragged_text).on('end', dragended));
                    }
                }

                //svg.on('click', main);

                function mousedown() {
                    var lnk = $('#dv_conv').find('a[data-pressed="1"]');
                    var conv = lnk.attr('data-conv');

                    if (conv == 3) {
                        var m = d3.mouse(this);
                        line = container.append('line').attr('x1', m[0]).attr('y1', m[1]).attr('x2', m[0]).attr('y2', m[1]).attr('stroke', '#000').attr('stroke-width', 2).attr('fill', 'transparent').on('click', clicked).call(d3.drag().on("start", dragstarted).on("drag", dragged_line).on("end", dragended));
                        svg.on('mousemove', mousemove);
                    }

                    if (conv == 6) {
                        var m = d3.mouse(this);
                        var lineGenerator = d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal);

                        pointspath[pointspath.length] = [m[0], m[1]];
                        pointspath[pointspath.length] = [m[0], m[1]];

                        var pathData = lineGenerator(pointspath);
                        path = container.append('path').attr('d', pathData).attr('stroke', '#000').attr('stroke-width', 1).attr('fill', 'transparent').on('click', clicked).call(d3.drag().on("start", dragstarted).on("drag", dragged_path).on("end", dragended));
                        svg.on('mousemove', mousemove);
                    }
                }

                function mousemove() {
                    var lnk = $('#dv_conv').find('a[data-pressed="1"]');
                    var conv = lnk.attr('data-conv');
                    if (conv == 3) {
                        var m = d3.mouse(this);
                        line.attr('x2', m[0]).attr('y2', m[1]);
                        console.log('x=' + m[0] + 'y=' + m[1]);
                    }

                    if (conv == 6) {
                        var lineGenerator = d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal);
                        var m = d3.mouse(this);
                        pointspath[pointspath.length] = [m[0], m[1]];
                        var pathData = lineGenerator(pointspath);
                        path.attr('d', pathData);
                    }
                }

                function mouseup() {
                    svg.on('mousemove', null);
                    svg.on('click', null);
                }

                function dragstarted(d) {
                    d3.select(this).raise().classed('active', true);
                }

                function dragged_circle(d) {
                    d3.select(this).attr('cx', +d3.select(this).attr('cx') + d3.event.dx);
                    d3.select(this).attr('cy', +d3.select(this).attr('cy') + d3.event.dy);
                }

                function dragged_rect(d) {
                    d3.select(this).attr('x', +d3.select(this).attr('x') + d3.event.dx);
                    d3.select(this).attr('y', +d3.select(this).attr('y') + d3.event.dy);
                }

                function dragged_text(d) {
                    d3.select(this).attr('x', +d3.select(this).attr('x') + d3.event.dx);
                    d3.select(this).attr('y', +d3.select(this).attr('y') + d3.event.dy);
                }

                function dragged_line(d) {
                    this.x = this.x || 0;
                    this.y = this.y || 0;
                    this.x += d3.event.dx;
                    this.y += d3.event.dy;
                    d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.x + ',' + this.y + ')');
                }

                function dragged_path(d) {
                    this.x = this.x || 0;
                    this.y = this.y || 0;
                    this.x += d3.event.dx;
                    this.y += d3.event.dy;
                    d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.x + ',' + this.y + ')');
                }

                function dragged_woman() {
                    this.x = this.x || 0;
                    this.y = this.y || 0;
                    this.x += d3.event.dx;
                    this.y += d3.event.dy;
                    d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.x + ',' + this.y + ')');
                }

                function dragended(d) {
                    d3.select(this).classed('active', false);
                }

                d3.select('body').on('keydown', function () {
                    if (d3.event.keyCode === 27) {
                        $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                        svg.on('mousemove', null);

                        var lnk = $('#dv_conv').find('a[data-pressed="1"]');
                        var conv = lnk.attr('data-conv');
                        if (conv == 3) {
                            svg.on('click', mousedown);
                        }
                    }
                });

                function clicked(d, i) {
                    var lnk = $('#dv_conv').find('a[data-pressed="1"]');
                    var conv = lnk.attr('data-conv');
                    if (conv == 20) {
                        d3.select(this).remove();
                    } else if (conv == 6) {
                        pointspath = new Array();
                        /*var element = $(this).prop('tagName');*/

                    }
                }

                $('#lnk_circle').click(function () {
                    svg.on('click', main);
                    $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                    return false;
                });

                $('#lnk_rectangle').click(function () {
                    svg.on('click', main);
                    $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                    return false;
                });

                $('#lnk_line').click(function () {
                    svg.on('click', mousedown).on("dblclick", mouseup);
                    $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                    return false;
                });

                $('#lnk_path').click(function () {
                    svg.on('click', mousedown).on("dblclick", mouseup);
                    $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                    return false;
                });

                $('#lnk_text').click(function () {
                    svg.on('click', main);
                    $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                    return false;
                });

                $('#lnk_erase').click(function () {
                    svg.on('click', null);
                    $('#lnk_circle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $('#lnk_rectangle').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $('#lnk_line').attr('data-pressed', 0);
                    $(this).attr('data-pressed', 1);
                    return false;
                });

                $('#dv_member').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    height: 260,
                    width: 450,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        Guardar: function () {
                            save_member();
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        },
                        Cancelar: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    close: function () {
                        $('#txt_name,#txt_age,#txt_job').val('');
                    }
                });

                $('#svf').on('contextmenu', '.gwoman', function () {
                    object = $(this);

                    var circle = object.find('circle.woman');
                    var cx = +circle.attr('cx'),
                            cy = +circle.attr('cy'),
                            coords = getScreenCoords(cx, cy, circle);
                    alert(circle.attr('cx'));
                    console.log(coords.x, coords.y);
                    return false;
                });

                function getScreenCoords(x, y, element) {
                    var ctm = element.getScreenCTM();
                    var xn = ctm.e + x * ctm.a + y * ctm.c;
                    var yn = ctm.f + x * ctm.b + y * ctm.d;
                    return {x: xn, y: yn};
                }

            });
        </script>
        <style>
            line,circle,rect,polyline{ shape-rendering:crispEdges;} 

            text{
                webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
            }
        </style>                
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dv_fam">
            <div id="dv_conv" style="float: left;width:200px;border:1px solid #000;margin-right: 1px">
                <a href="#" id="lnk_circle" data-pressed="0" data-conv="1">Circle</a><br/>
                <a href="#" id="lnk_rectangle" data-pressed="0" data-conv="2">Rectangle</a><br/>
                <a href="#" id="lnk_line" data-pressed="0" data-conv="3">Line</a><br/>
                <a href="#" id="lnk_text" data-pressed="0" data-conv="5">Text</a><br/>
                <a href="#" id="lnk_path" data-pressed="0" data-conv="6">Path</a><br/>
                <a href="#" id="lnk_erase" data-pressed="0" data-conv="20">Erase</a><br/>
            </div>

            <div id="dv_familiogram" style="float: left;width:500px;height: 500px;border:1px solid #000;overflow: hidden">
                <svg id="svf"  style="width:500px;height:500px"></svg>
            </div>

            <div id="dv_member" title="">
                <div>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="txt_name" maxlength="100"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Job</label>
                    <input type="text" id="txt_job" maxlength="100"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Age</label>
                    <input type="text" id="txt_age" maxlength="3"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the link did not produce the error in Chrome

Comment: It's with the right click

Comment: The error appears when doing `var ctm = element.getScreenCTM();`. On that line `element` refers to a jQuery object which, obviously, has no `.getScreenCTM()` method. You need to get the DOM element from the jQuery object to call that method: `var ctm = element.get(0).getScreenCTM();`.

Comment: You are right, thank you